# Count all HTML tags in page PHP

Tags: php, html, regex

I spent time on regex to solve this problem but not have result
i try solve this problem using PHP 5.3
Information like  - How many times repeats in page and information about all tags in page.

Comment: please post what you tried. If you just want a count of dom elements you would probably get a better result out of javascript, but php can do it using libxml... assuming it is valid xhtml.

Comment: If you're doing it from PHP, you should use the [DOMDocument class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). See Gordon's answer here: [str_replace within certain html tags only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172493/str-replace-within-certain-html-tags-only)

Comment: I try love this problem using reg exp and substr
logic was next
all page convert to 1 long string
find html tag and cont all another in text after remove all and count next

Answer (score 19):

Your question is unfortunately barely understandable in it's current form. Please try to update it and be more specific. If you want to *count all HTML tags in a page*, you can do:

```
$HTML = <<< HTML
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Some Text</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello World<br/>
            <img src="earth.jpg" alt="picture of earth from space"/>
        <p>
        <p>Counting Elements is easy with DOM</p>
    </body>
</html>
HTML;
```

Counting all DOMElements with DOM:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($HTML);
$allElements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('*');
echo $allElements->length;
```

The above will output `8`, because there is eight elements in the DOM. If you also need to know *the distribution of elements*, you can do

```
$elementDistribution = array();
foreach($allElements as $element) {
    if(array_key_exists($element->tagName, $elementDistribution)) {
        $elementDistribution[$element->tagName] += 1;
    } else {
        $elementDistribution[$element->tagName] = 1;
    }
}
print_r($elementDistribution);
```

This would return

```
Array (
    [html] => 1
    [head] => 1
    [title] => 1
    [body] => 1
    [p] => 2
    [br] => 1
    [img] => 1
)
```

Note that getElementsByTagName returns [DOMElements](http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) only. It does not take into account closing tags, nor does it return other DOMNodes. If you also need to count closing tags and other node types, consider using [XMLReader](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php) instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
$testHTML = file_get_contents('index.html');

$search = preg_match_all('/<([^\/!][a-z1-9]*)/i',$testHTML,$matches);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($matches[1]);
echo '</pre>';
```

Gives you an array of all the tags. Once the data is in the array, you can use all the standard PHP array functions - e.g. array_count_values() - to extract the details you want... though you're not really saying what information you want about the html tags

Using array_count_values() with the results of the preg_match_all():

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump(array_count_values($matches[1]));
echo '</pre>';
```

gives

```
array(5) {
  ["html"]=>
  int(1)
  ["head"]=>
  int(1)
  ["title"]=>
  int(1)
  ["body"]=>
  int(1)
  ["h1"]=>
  int(2)
}
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: information need like div - 5  a - 7 p - 22

Maby DOMDocument is not best solve for this task ?

Comment: Yes 
Thank you very much this is what I have so long tormented
It great answer 
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you checkout `simple html dom`

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Comment: Its a big package for 1 simple task :/