# A good methodology for obtaining the number of html tags for a page

Tags: php, dom, curl, depth, scraper

I'm looking for a good way to do this: my current method seems to not allow depths of searches beyond 30-40, even after editing the `php.ini` settings in hopes to increase default execution time as well as max memory usage. Basically, as soon as the depth of search exceeds this amount, the server crashes.

Here is my code (`private function _ParseHtml($html, $depth = nDepth`):

```
        if ($depth === 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        @$this->_dom->loadHTML($html);

        $this->nodes = $this->_dom->childNodes;

        $html = array();
        $iterCount = 0;

        foreach($this->nodes as $node)
        {
            if($node->hasChildNodes())
            {
                $html[$iterCount++] = $node->C14N();    
            }

            $this->_tagCount++;

            if ( $this->_config['Debug'] ) _wrapBreak("Tag Count incremented");
        }

        if( count( $html ) > 0 )
        {
            $static_depth = $depth - 1;

            foreach( $html as $parse )
            {
                $this->_ParseHtml( $parse, $static_depth );

                if ( $this->_config['Debug'] ) _wrapBreak("ParseHtml did return");
            }
        }

        _wrapBreak("<strong>Current Depth</strong> => <strong>{$depth}</strong>");
```

As well as the main code for the scrape `_Invoke()` function:

```
             $handle = curl_init($this->_url);

         curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, self::BUFSIZE); //BUFSIZE == 50000
         curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
         curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

         $this->_data['html'] = curl_exec($handle);

         curl_close($handle);

     $this->_ParseHtml($this->_data['html']);
```

Answer (score 1):

The number of HTML tags should be easily obtainable though

```
$this->_dom->getElementsByTagName("*")->length;
```

Answer (score 1):

As found here: [Count all HTML tags in page PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3184284/1300235)

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($HTML);
$allElements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('*');
echo $allElements->length;
```

Although the example in the link does not get event close to the number of nested levels that you have...