# Parsing html to retrieve tags

Tags: php, html, parsing, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Count all HTML tags in page PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184284/count-all-html-tags-in-page-php)
>   [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

I am having trouble with parsing information to retrieve a list of html and meta tags used in a HTML documents and the number of times each tag occurs in the document.

So for example if I had the following html document

```
 <head>
 <a href="example.com">example1</a>
 <a href="example.com">example2</a>
 <a href="example.com">example3</a>
 </head>
```

Then you would get a list like

```
head tag =1
a tag =3
```

I am trying to do this with php, if anyone could even give me a starting point that would be great.

Edit:
I am trying to replicate something like the following python code but with php

```
  class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
  def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
  print "Encountered a start tag:", tag
  def handle_endtag(self, tag):
  print "Encountered an end tag :", tag
  def handle_data(self, data):
 print "Encountered some data  :", data
```

Comment: In a sense yes, I did read that post but I am more so having trouble with just recognizing when a html tag occurs. I am looking to do something like the python code on example 19.1.1 at the following link: http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html but can't seem to figure out how to perform a similar task with php

Answer (score 2):

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php for parsing the DOM in PHP (e.g., starting with the method http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php ). See also http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php for any other APIs.