# Count html tags by php in string

Tags: php

Hi there I am requesting you to tell me the simple php script to count special html tag, like <p> in string. I had no idea to try this, since I am the beginner in php.

Comment: "Gimme $5 and I'll do your homework."  Seriously, this is a Q/A site, not a "gimme teh codez" do it for you site.

Answer (score 6):

You can make use of [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) Class for that .

```
<?php
$html='<p>Hey hello</p><b>Hey this is bold tag</b><p>Another paragraph</p>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
echo $dom->getElementsByTagName('p')->length;// "prints" 2
```

Comment: there is a very good answer here to read ALL of them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184284/count-all-html-tags-in-page-php

Answer (score 4):

use a substr_count() function for find a mached substring from string:

```
  <?PHP
    $text = 'This is a test';
    //Use substr_count for search matched string
    echo substr_count($text, 'is'); // 2

    ?>
```