# PHP: Get no of elements by classname

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

```
<html>
<body>

<p class="class1" id="id1"  > some data 1</p>
<p class="class1" id="id2"  > some data 2</p>
<p class="class1" id="id3"  > some data 3</p>

</body>
</html>
```

like in javascript following code will do the job

```
var elems=document.getElementsByClassName("class1");

var length = elems.length;
```

how to do same in php so that i can iterate it that many times?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184284/count-all-html-tags-in-page-php

Answer (score 2):

[PHP code demo](https://eval.in/765748)

Using XPath: `//*[@class="class1"]`

```
<?php
$object = new DOMDocument();
$object->loadHTML('<html>
<body>

<p class="class1" id="id1"  > some data 1</p>
<p class="class1" id="id2"  > some data 2</p>
<p class="class1" id="id3"  > some data 3</p>
<p class="class1" id="id3"  > some data 4</p>

</body>
</html>');

$xpath = new DOMXpath($object);
$elements = $xpath->query('//*[@class="class1"]');
$noOfElements=$elements->length;
echo $noOfElements;
```